# How to use Interaction Triggers for maximizing and minimizing WPF window using c# with mvvm pattern?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-4.5

I can close a window using Interaction Triggers like

```
            <Button Content="X" Height="20" Width="20">
                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                        <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="Close"
                            TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                        Mode=FindAncestor,
                        AncestorType=Window}}" />
                    </i:EventTrigger>
                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            </Button>
```

But when I replace **MethodName="Close"** with **MethodName="Maximize"** or **MethodName="Minimize"** to maximize or minimize window it doesn't work.

How do I do this using .Net 4.5 without breaking mvvm pattern ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MethodName="Close"` works because there is `Close()` method in `Window` type, but there is no `Maximize()` or `Minimize()` methods out there, these are states, there is `WindowState` property that you can set to Minimize or Maximize..

1. You can change it explicitly when the button is clicked

```
void Button_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.WindowState = Maximize;
}
```

2. Or you can define your own window that has `Minimize()` and `Maximize()` methods..

```
public class MyWindow : Window {

    public void Maximize(){
        this.WindowState = Maximize;
    }
    
    public void Minimize(){
        this.WindowState = Minimize;
    }
}
```

And in .xaml

```
<views:MyWindow [views namespace here]..
    <!-- -->
    <Button Content="X" Height="20" Width="20">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <i:CallMethodAction MethodName="Maximize"
                    TargetObject="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                Mode=FindAncestor,
                AncestorType=MyWindow}}" />
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </Button>
    <!-- -->
</Window>
```

Comment: I'm trying not to brake the mvvm pattern, so `Button_OnClick` is not an option. So, where do I define `CurWindowState` and how ? Also, how do I use this in my interaction trigger approach exactly ?

Comment: I've updated the answer.. MVVM speaking, I'd like to tell you that `Button_OnClick` is the preferred option! I can't imagine that changing the WindowState could be part of the business logic! so why to make the viewmodel responsible for doing this pure UI-Task?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here (I'm still new to mvvm), your'e saying that if I do  `<Button Click="button_Click"/>` in xaml and then do your 1st option in code behind it will not break the mvvm pattern? I thought using button click event in code behind is no the mvvm way.

Comment: MVVM doesn't mean to make ViewMode responsible about everything.. MVVM means, when you look at the top of the ViewModel file, you should find not a single using statement related to any UI component!

Comment: In MVVM, you should not write UI code in ViewModel.. all UI code should be in View part..

Comment: Ok, but just for knowledge, how can I do window maximizing/minimizing using interaction triggers? If that is possible without adding way too many lines of code that is ...

Comment: I've updated the answer again to show how to do that.. notice that `AncestorType` is `MyWindow`

Comment: Thanks for the effort :) Really appreciate it...

Comment: I'll remove the 3ed option, you can find it in the activities of the answer if you want.. you're welcome